# Add element to a view of a mobile application in actionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, air

I have a program with a list of item. An item is an actionScript class that extends View. When I click on the list, it push the view. In the constructor of this class I add some buttons and I have a function that add another button.
My problem is that the view display only the button create in the constructor and not the one create in the function.

The class

```
package 
{   

    import spark.components.Button;

    public class Application extends View
    {       
        public function Application()
        {
            var bt:Button = new Button();
            bt.label = "In C";
            addElement(bt);
        }

        public function addButton():void {          
            var b:Button = new Button();
            b.label = "Olé";
            addElement(b);
            visible = true;         
        }       
    }
}
```

The firstView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home"
    visible="false" creationComplete="retrieveApplication(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import ...

        protected function retrieveApplication(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            ...
            var application:Application = new Application();
            ...                     
            application.addButton();
            this.visible = true;
        }

        protected function launchApplication(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            navigator.pushView(Application);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button x="10" y="10" width="460" label="Button" click="launchApplication(event)"/>
```

That did I do wrong?

Comment: are you getting any errors? Or is it just not showing up? I dont know if the special character "e" would cause problems - but it may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you pass a class reference to the pushView , not an instance. That means you don't pass the application instance you created in the retrieveApplication method.

Flex instanciates itself an instance of the view after you call pushView. So the addButton method is never called.

Comment: Flex instanciates itself an instance of the view after you call pushView... 
How can I display a view that I create in and actionScript class?
I create a classe that create a view, parse a xml file that tell what visual elements to put, create them and add to the view.
 And I want to display it, so how can I do it?

Comment: I think there is a viewAdded event available in View classes. Don't create an AS class, create a MXML View component and add a listener on viewAdded. In your listener, parse your XML and create the visual elements.